# How do I resolve .husky/_/husky.sh: No such file or directory error when using husky?

Tags: git, husky, git-husky

A project that I'm working on with colleagues uses husky versions ^5.1.0 and I keep getting this error when I'm trying to push my commit.

```
.husky/_/husky.sh: No such file or directory
```

How do I resolve this?

I'm currently using git version 2.18.0.

I have referred to https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/712 and https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/242 but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I eventually figured out that I had to delete node_modules and reinstall using

```
yarn install
```

But this caused the .husky/_/husky.sh to be added to the commit which my colleagues did not want.

In order to avoid that I just had to update my git version via homebrew.

I just ran

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

The brew update command updates homebrew itself, and the brew upgrade command updates all packages installed via homebrew.

My git was updated to version 2.30.2

This allows the nested .gitignore file to ignore the .husky/_/husky.sh file in our project.

Answer (score 5):

In my current scenario I was able to resolve the problem running `npx husky-init` and discarding all the changes it made to the files.

Comment: where did you run npx husky-init?

Comment: i mean, where directory?

Comment: I run it in the root directory of the repository

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command after remove file: _/husky.sh

```
git config --unset core.hooksPath
```

Answer (score 0):

If this could help someone who had same issue as me

I had the following code in the
`.husky/commit-msg`

`npx --no -- commitlint --edit "${1}"`

and just removing the `"`, it worked for me i.e
`npx --no -- commitlint --edit ${1}`